Probability of Acceptance After Two Minor Revisions
I submitted an article to a Springer journal on November 25, 2023. I received a major revision in March with comments from Reviewer 1 only. In the second round, I received a minor revision with comments from both Reviewer 1 and Reviewer 2, which I addressed thoroughly. Now, in the third round, I have received another minor revision with comments from Reviewer 3. I submitted the revised version with a point-by-point response yesterday.Given this situation, do I have a high probability of receiving an acceptance decision?

This is very tough to say. Might vary a fair bit in terms of journal, subfield, the individual referees, and other factors.

Isn’t the probability of acceptance with minor revisions generally very close to 100%? At least that’s how it is in mathematics. It means the journal already basically approves of your paper and just wants you to correct a few small things. There isn’t much that can go wrong at that point. But I can’t speak to what happens in other disciplines

We've got a rejection after a minor revision. Turned out this was due to sloppy work by one of the reviewers that thought having found an error on the second round and the decision was successfully appealed. However, if they indeed had found an error, it might still have ended with a rejection.

You might be interested in the second part of my answer here: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/191281/is-there-any-other-chance-for-looking-to-the-paper-after-rejection With two minor revisions, the probability of acceptance goes up (but it's still not 100%).

Nobody can know, not any of us and not you. Generally, minor revisions lead to accepted papers, but not always. All you can do is do the requested revisions the best you can, and hope that it satisfies the editor and the reviewers. Beyond that, things are not under your control and the right thing to do is use your mental energy for the next paper you're working on.
